# What is code to increase text size?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have the code below and I want to increase text size of output `e.VoltageRatio.ToString("E3")` and `("F3")`.

How do I do this?

```
void ratio_change(
         object sender, 
         Phidget22.Events.VoltageRatioInputVoltageRatioChangeEventArgs e) 
{
    if (ratio.ChannelSubclass == ChannelSubclass.VoltageRatioInputBridge)
        voltageTxt.Text = e.VoltageRatio.ToString("E3") + " V/V Test";
    else
        voltageTxt.Text = e.VoltageRatio.ToString("F3") + " V/V Test";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before asking a question, read [ask] and try searching.

Comment: I still dont know how to insert code or what code to make it work. Im not really a programmer. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Still cant figure out - any help appreciated Code Caster

Comment: See the duplicate.

Comment: I have seen and tried but get errors. Maybe I can hire someone to figure out?